# how to add custom HTML form in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have HTML5 form with text box and a submit button,like below

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

and how can I use above html code in drupal??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, easiest way for creating forms would be by using webform module. It's easy to use, intuitive, but again powerful:

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-features

So, my suggestion is to use it and add some CSS if you need to style your form.

Second way, would be by using Drupal's form api. For this you'll have to check on documentation, read some tutorial or similar.Requires some programming skills. 
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api

Third way would be creating totally custom page end-point, where you can literally copy-paste your code as it is:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-page